# VBA Excel duplicate the existing sheet with number based on the previous sheet duplicated

Tags: excel, vba

Regarding the last query:

VBA Excel add new sheet with number based on the previous sheet created

I would like to duplicate the existing sheet and then add it under the incremented number, although on the same basis as mentioned in my previous query. I want to have the sheet number based on the last sheet number created.

If I take into account for example this code:

```
  Public Sub CreateSheet()
  Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim startNmae As String: startName = "Area Map "
  Dim counter As Integer: counter = 1

  For Each ws In wb.Sheets                      
  If Left(ws.Name, Len(startName)) = startName Then
    counter = counter + 1
  End If            
  Next was

  Set ws = wb.Sheets.Copy
  startName = startName & counter
  ws.Name = startName
  End Sub
```

I am getting an error: **Expected function or variable**

with debugger showing the line:

```
 Set ws = wb.Sheets.Copy
```

[image]

The other approaches also weren't working

```
  Sub Newsheets()
  Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim startName As String: startName = "Area Map "
  Dim counter As Integer: counter = 1

  For Each ws In wb.Sheets
  If Left(ws.Name, Len(startName)) = startName Then
    counter = counter + 1
  End If
  Next was

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Area Map" & counter)
  With was
 .Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
 startName = startName & counter
 .Name = startName
 End With
 End Sub
```

Now I am getting: **Subscript out of range**, for the following line

```
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Area Map" & counter)
```

The next option wasn't successful either:

```
Sub ConsecutiveNumberSheets2()
Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
Dim i As Long
Dim startName As String: startName = "Area Map "
Dim counter As Integer: counter = 1

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Area Map 1")

For Each ws In wb.Sheets
If Left(ws.Name, Len(startName)) = startName Then
    counter = counter + 1
End If
Next was

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count - (Sheets.Count - 1)
With Sheets("Area Map 1")
.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
 ActiveSheet.Name = "Area Map" & counter + 1
.Select
End With
Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

I need to have the sheet copied under the incremented number. I would like to base the incrementation on the last existing number of the sheet. Is it possible?

Comment: `wb.Sheets.Copy` cannot work and throws an error because `Sheets` is a collection of *all* sheets of a workbook. If you want to copy a sheet, you need to use something like `wb.Sheets(1).Copy` or `wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy`

Comment: subscript out of range is because it looks like your sheet has a space between "Map" and the number but your code does not.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is base on total number of sheets with similar or the same name occurring throughout our workbook.

The solution can be found here:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5098-excel-vba-count-sheets-with-specific-name.html

If we determine the number of sheets with specific name, then copying them only once a few times won't be a problem.

The final code could look as follows:

```
 Sub Consecutivesheetduplicate()
 Dim wsr as Worksheet
 Dim I As Long
 Dim xCount As Integer

 Set wsr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Area Map 1")

 For I = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    If InStr(1, Sheets(I).Name, "Area") > 0 Then xCount = xCount + 1
 Next

 For I = 1 To Sheets.Count - (Sheets.Count - 1)
 On Error Resume Next
 With Sheets("Area Map 1")
 .Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wsr.Index + xCount + I)
 ActiveSheet.Name = "Area Map " & xCount + 1
 .Select
 End With
 Next I

 End Sub
```